# 'list' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Tags: python, django, image-upload

I want to upload the profile picture. the image is not getting uploaded. It gives the error AttributeError at /profile/

'list' object has no attribute 'startswith'

```
def userDetail(request):
current_user = request.user
if(request.method == 'POST'):
    form = UserDetailDataForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if(form.is_valid()):
        profileImg = request.FILES['profileImg']
        try:
            userprofile = UserDetail.objects.get(user_id = current_user.id)
            if userprofile:
                userprofile.profileImg = profileImg
                userprofile.save()

        context = {'username': current_user.username, 'image' : userprofile.profileImg,                                                'MEDIA_ROOT': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}
        return render_to_response('user_profile.html', context)
else:
    form = UserDetailDataForm()
return render_to_response('profile.html', {'form': form})
```

Models.py

`profileImg = models.ImageField(upload_to='/images/',blank=True, null=True,default="images/default-profile.jpg")`

Settings file:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
MEDIA_ROOT = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'firstapp/static/'),]
```

Full StackTrace:

```
    Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/profile/

Django Version: 1.10.5
Python Version: 2.7.12
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'firstapp',
 'events',
 'django_extensions']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/var/www/html/myproject/firstapp/views.py" in userDetail
  161.                  userprofile.save()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py" in save
  80.         super(AbstractBaseUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  796.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  824.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
  886.                       for f in non_pks]

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py" in pre_save
  292.             file.save(file.name, file, save=False)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py" in save
  91.         self.name = self.storage.save(name, content, max_length=self.field.max_length)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/files/storage.py" in save
  53.         name = self.get_available_name(name, max_length=max_length)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/files/storage.py" in get_available_name
  77.         while self.exists(name) or (max_length and len(name) > max_length):

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/files/storage.py" in exists
  394.         return os.path.exists(self.path(name))

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/files/storage.py" in path
  407.         return safe_join(self.location, name)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in __get__
  35.         res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/files/storage.py" in location
  283.         return abspathu(self.base_location)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/_os.py" in abspathu
  30.         if not isabs(path):

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py" in isabs
  54.     return s.startswith('/')

Exception Type: AttributeError at /profile/
Exception Value: 'list' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Comment: Full stacktrace?

Comment: I have edited the post.

Answer (score 6):

[`MEDIA_ROOT` setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#media-root) should be a *string*, not a list:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'firstapp/static/')
```

Comment: I have multiple paths in MEDIA_ROOT

MEDIA_ROOT = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'firstapp/static/'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'events/static/'),
]

Comment: @ManpreetAhluwalia right, please follow the common way static files are gathered from the django project apps (@Tryph's answer is about it). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have static files in multiple apps, you should look at the [staticfiles app doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/staticfiles/) which allows you to collect static files of multiple apps in one unique location that you able to point in your `STATIC_ROOT` setting.